# GITHUB pages noe showing images on my project

Tags: html, css, github, deployment, github-pages

I added a project site to my Github project. But all the photos are not displaying in the site.

The Code I used is
`<img src="/images/image-daniel.jpg" alt="">`

I saw some solutions before and updated my code to
`<img src="images/image-daniel.jpg" alt="">`
But when I go to the inspect It still shows the code
`<img src="/images/image-daniel.jpg" alt="">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the entire Project from Github and update the src attribute to `<img src="images/image-daniel.jpg"` and upload the Project again .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).